# MySQL - How to find which sql query is being executed

Tags: sql, mysql

How can i find which query is being executed in mysql.
Example : I have a java application which makes several calls to the database, i want to track the queries executed by this application from the sql side.

Thanks
Micheal

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
show processlist;
```

...to show you the running queries on your MySQL server.  For more info: [Showing running queries in MySQL](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/show-running-queries-mysql/)

```
show full processlist
```

...will show the complete query of all connected clients.

Comment: this will show the process list , i want to see the actual query at the give point.

Comment: `show full processlist` will show the complete query of all connected clients.

Answer (score 3):

`show processlist` will tell you what each thread is doing on MySQL server.